# Convert numpy matrix to pandas dataframe or series by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a numpy matrix and I'd like to convert it to a pandas dataframe/series. An example:

```
m = np.array([[1, 2], [11, 22]])
```

which would result in

```
        a
0   [1,   2]
1   [11, 22]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
m = np.array([[1, 2], [11, 22]])
pd.DataFrame({'col':[z for z in m]})

    col
0   [1, 2]
1   [11, 22]
```

Or, as per @pault

```
pd.DataFrame({'col':list(m)})

    col
0   [1, 2]
1   [11, 22]
```

Comment: Didn't think it was worth posting as a separate answer, but you can also do: `pd.DataFrame({'a': list(m)})`

Answer (score 2):

Just using `Series`+`to_frame`

```
pd.Series(m.tolist()).to_frame('yourcolum')
Out[75]: 
  yourcolum
0    [1, 2]
1  [11, 22]
```

Comment: Great solution too